# How to perform arithmetic operations on multiple attributes in an expression using binding?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to implement an interactive program which return results of arithmetic operations performed on attributes entered by user. 
Tried to store the values of attributes dynamically and then access those values to perform operations on my given expressions like:
'x + y'
when x and y can assume arbitrary values. ( need to be fetched by user).

I am implementing below logic :

Take user input in a loop

```
There can be 3 cases now:
  Concat each input into a string
  ..
  execute the string if input is blank
  ..
  exit if key `q` is pressed
```

I have given inputs as x = 25 and y = 35, then tried to calculate 'x + y' expression . Faced error saying "`eval': undefined local variable or method`x' for Demo:Class"
Can someone please help me with this ?

```
class Demo
  def self.method(expr)
    if expr =~ /^.*=.*$/
      @object = eval(expr)
      get_binding
    else
      @object = eval(expr) 
      l_operand, op, r_operand = expr.partition(%r{[/*+-]})
      output = ''
      puts output += eval(l_operand)
      print output += op.to_s
      print output += eval(r_operand)
      @object =  eval(output)
      get_binding
    end
  end

  def self.get_binding
    binding
  end
end

user_input = ''
until user_input == 'q' do
 user_input = gets.chomp
   b3 = Demo.method(user_input)
   puts eval('@object', b3)
end
```

Expected Result: 
x+y 
=> 60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your `get_binding` is useless: it returns the current binding, but you don't assign it to anything, so it's forgotten.

Even if you used it, it would likely be incorrect: when you do `eval("x = 4")`, it creates a new binding, assigns `x` in that binding, and then destroys the binding since you're not using it any more. A subsequent `binding` call will instantiate a *new* binding, unrelated to the one that was inside `eval`, and then `binding.eval("x")` will complain (rightly) that `x` is unknown. You have to return the `eval` binding for future evaluations.

This would work:

```
current_binding = binding
value, current_binding = current_binding.eval('[x = 25, binding]')
value, current_binding = current_binding.eval('[y = 35, binding]')
value, current_binding = current_binding.eval('[x + y, binding]')
value
# => 60
```

Two key points: you need to take the binding from inside the `eval` to preserve the values in it, and you need to start the evaluation with the previously captured binding.

It would be irresponsible to not also note that passing user input into `eval` is extremely dangerous from the security standpoint, especially if you're accepting input from somewhere that normally doesn't have your level of access to the system (e.g. a website). For example, an input of `` `rm -rf ~` `` would delete all of your files.

EDIT: Per comment, here's a short demo of the concept (I can't implement it in your code, as it has too many errors):

```
current_binding = binding
until (line = gets.chomp!) == 'q'
  value, current_binding = current_binding.eval("[#{line}, binding]")
  puts value unless value.nil?
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir... that was a great advise.

Comment: Sir I'm trying to implement it in my code but failing to do so, can you please help me with that.. I am still unclear how to I implement it in my code.